# Encoding issue when opening text file with Django url

Tags: python, django

I have a simple text file with accents in `django` media. The file is encoded in `UTF8`. When I open it with my browser `/home/xxx/my_django_app/media/changelog.txt`, the accents are displayed.

On the other hand, when I open it via `django` directly with the url `localhost:8000/media/changelog.txt`, the accents are not displayed, as if the file was not in `UTF8`.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: *open it via django directly with the url* try to encode before opening it or provide code how you tried to serve file.

Comment: I only have an `<a>` tag in HTML with an `href` attribute to this file